# Acoustic treatment for glass

Tags: glass, echo, acoustics, handling

I have searched for a bit but haven't found much on this but maybe some of you have fixed a similar problem in the past:

Can I put something over glass to make it anechoic?

It's a long shot, but I figured I'd ask you guys since most of you do a lot of recording in studios.

My studio has a large glass sliding door to get into it and it's about 60% of one of the walls. I can position the talents to face away from it but is there anything I can put over the glass and lessen it's echo with still being able to see through it?

Let me know if I'm crazy for asking/trying.

Answer (score 4):

Anything that I can think of to put over it is going to obscure your line of site.  I initially thought multiple curtains of thin, gauzy, nearly transparent fabrics at spaced intervals; but the more I thought about it, the more likely it is that you won't be able to see through it as you add more layers.  Plus it would be a pain in the butt to walk in and out through.

How big is your studio? Perhaps you can further treat the other walls or use some baffles, walk around and find the dryest area in the room and put them there.

Uhhhh...now that I've mentioned baffles, I've realized that they don't have to cover all of the glass.  Maybe some free standing baffles that only come up to somewhere around shoulder height...or one that has a "window" built into it that you can see through but still covers most of your glass?  I suppose some reduction is better than none

Those are the best solutions I can come up with.  Hopefully someone else will have something a little more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Room is about 10x13. Nice idea on the baffle.

Comment: yes baffles! Especially a baffle that leaves space for the talent to see the engineering room. Or use sonic foam treatment and leave out a smaller window for the talent to use.

Comment: Yeah that's a great idea. I think the baffle is the way to go because I don't think it will fly to put foam over the window and make a smaller window.

Answer (score 4):

Someone from MIT should develop transparent sonic foam with the multiple pyramids placed all over to disperse sound. Wait a minute. I'm going to develop it myself. But instead of a foam, it will be a clear gel that can stick to glass. It's brilliant! I'll need a pen and paper and some US patent forms. I'll be right back.

Comment: lol. I'll be your first buyer.

Comment: Hubert Campbell where did you go I am still waiting :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest to measure the room´s dimensions first,
make a draft, 
then think of the reflection points FROM the glass and Your listening position.
treating the ceiling and ground would be needful.

I also see some acoustic baffle in use.
Or hang some absorbers and use sth. like a curtain rail to move them.
Measure again.

Happy drawing

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Happy new year Ryan. DIY acoustic treatment is going to be difficult without creating a visual barrier. I did come across [Clear Sonic Panels](http://www.clearsonic.com/csp.htm) which may be of some help.